# How can I access the Gmail contacts on an Android tablet?

Tags: contacts, gmail

I am helping a friend who has an Android tablet with an app for Gmail. Her mail contacts appear if she starts typing a name, but she wants to be able to go to Contacts and check off multiple people to send mail to. We cannot find any access to Gmail contacts without going through the browser to the full Gmail site.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which tablet it is. Is there a "People" app? That should be syncing with Google Contacts. Either way, you can enter multiple names in the "To:" field.

Comment: I believe it is an Acer tablet. She can manually add addressees, but she likes to look at her "Address Book" (Contacts) and check off the names so that they are automatically entered in the "To" field. I'll have to look for a "People" app.

Answer (score 2):

You can access to them through the "`Contact`" app of your tablet. If you do not see them at first sight, go to the parameters to select the contacts you want to show.

Answer (score 1):

Syncing of Google Contacts must be enabled in the system settings in order to see them in the Contacts app.  This can normally be found under `Settings > Accounts > Google > *YourEmail@gmail.com* > Sync Contacts`.  Just make sure it is checked.

Answer (score 0):

One way is also to open [Google contacts preview](https://contacts.google.com) interface in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

In my Samsung Galaxy Tab E, I go to Apps, Then to Contacts. Really stupid and cumbersome, I know, but it is what it is.